# How to display a region in all the pages of an application in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-19.2

I'm working on an app in Oracle Apex. It has a lot of pages. I want to have a region at the top of the page displaying some important information. It is the same for all the pages.

I can do this by copying the region from page to page but it is a hideous process.

Is there some way to create some kind of region which can be displayed on all the pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a region on page 0, that is the global page. Anything on that page is rendered on all pages.